# what are the reasons for getting this "the requested resource is not available" in spring mvc?

Tags: spring, hibernate, resources

I am developing a spring mvc application.Until now I was just calling the controller which in turn was
displaying the login.jsp page.The project was running successfully.

But when I wanted to add database connection with hibernate, there was nothing to change in web.xml
class.I added new things to my dispatcher-servlet.xml, gave required annotations to my DTOs and
service classes.

Now when I run the project it says `The Requested Resource is not available`.
What I think if there were any problem in my dispatcher-servlet.xml due to adding new things regarding
hibernate connection and mapping, then at least my index.jsp which is in <welcome-file> should have
been called.BUT NO.

Can anybody specify me what are the possible reasons for getting this problem.
Here is my dispatcher-servlet.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
xmlns:lang="http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang"
xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang/spring-lang.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd">

<context:component-scan base-package="com.alw" />

<bean id="viewResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix">
        <value>/WEB-INF/pages/</value>
    </property>
    <property name="suffix">
        <value>.jsp</value>
    </property>
</bean>

//codes below I added later  

<bean id="propertyConfigurer"
    class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer"
    p:location="/WEB-INF/jdbc.properties" />

<bean id="dataSource"
    class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close"
    p:driverClassName="${jdbc.driverClassName}"
    p:url="${jdbc.databaseurl}" p:username="${jdbc.username}"
    p:password="${jdbc.password}" />

<bean id="sessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="configLocation">
        <value>classpath:hibernate.cfg.xml</value>
    </property>
    <property name="configurationClass">
        <value>org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration</value>
    </property>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${jdbc.dialect}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.current_session_context_class">
                thread
            </prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<tx:annotation-driven />
<bean id="transactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>
```

Comment: Where you have put your index.jsp file in the directory structure?

Comment: Also if possible show the web.xml file

Answer (score 0):

The problem can be because of the view resolver code in your dispatcher-servlet.xml -

```
<bean id="viewResolver"     class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
  <property name="prefix"><value>/WEB-INF/pages/</value></property>
  <property name="suffix"><value>.jsp</value></property>
</bean>
```

Was this code also existing before you made the change ?

Comment: It is already there. He has mentioned that in the dispatcher xml.

Answer (score 0):

That usually means there was an upstream error starting the web app, and the entire web app failed initialization. You'd definitely notice something like that in the logs, though.